# 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port in k8s nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy Chartmuseum using HTTPS using nginx ingress controller in kubernetes.

My helm configuration is as follows, and when accessed with https, the server returns the following response.

```
> curl https://chartmuseum.mydomain.com
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.6</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Chartmuseum values**

```
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      annotations:
      hosts:
      - name: chartmuseum.mydomain.com
        path: /
        tls: true
      ingressClassName: nginx
```

**NGINX Ingress Controller values**

```
    controller:
      config:
        ssl-redirect: "false" # we use `special` port to control ssl redirection
        server-snippet: |
          listen 8000;
          if ( $server_port = 80 ) {
            return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
          }
          error_page 497 https://$host:30443$request_uri;
      containerPort:
        http: 80
        https: 443
        special: 8000
      service:
        targetPorts:
          http: http
          https: special
        annotations:
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: MY_ACM_ARN
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
```

The normal response I want is to connect to the chartmuseum with https.

**Additional Ref:**

- I have not registered any additional TLS Cert Secrets in Chartmuseum. The reason was thinking that TSL would be authenticated through ACM of NGINX Controller.
- Chartmuseum Helm Chart : https://chartmuseum.github.io/charts
- NGINX Ingress Controller Helm Chart : https://helm.nginx.com/stable

Thank you.

Comment: Both links you've provided for Chart sources are broken. Can you ensure you've installed the controller right?